# Problems with $f(x) \leq \lambda $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and such that $\forall x \in [a,b]:f(x) < 1$, there exists a $\lambda<1$ such that $\forall x \in [a,b]: f(x) \leq \lambda$

I have to decide if this sentence is true or false. My guess is that it is true, taking $ \lambda = \max \{ {f(x):x \in [a,b]\}}$ but I don’t quite know how to justify this sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track! You have to justify two more things:

1. $\max\{f(x)|x\in[a,b]\}$ *exists*. This is not always the case. For example, the function $f(x)=x$ does *not* have a maximum on $(0,1)$.
2. $\max\{f(x)|x\in[a,b]\}<1$. This should be clear from the definition of maximum.

Comment: $\max \{ {f(x): x \in [a,b] \} }$ exists since [a,b] is a bounded and closed interval and f is continuous on [a,b]. Would that argument be correct?

Comment: Oh, I just read @Fred argument and saw that he states the same as I, so I guess the existence would be proved like that.

Comment: @AngusL Exactly! Now, how do you know this maximum is less than $1$?

Comment: Don’t know how to prove that the maximum is < 1... I just think it’s obvious, but that wouldn’t be a correct argument

Comment: @AngusL If you can't prove it. it isn't obvious. What's the definition of maximum?

Comment: Since $\lambda$ is the maximum and we have proved that it exists, the hypothesis tells us that $\lambda < 1$ so $max < 1$

Comment: @AngusL The hypothesis doesn't tell you that $\lambda<1$. The hypothesis tells you $\forall x\in[a,b]: f(x)<1$

Comment: Oh you’re right, my bad. So, $\lambda$ is a maximum if $f(x) \leq \lambda \forall x \in [a,b]$ ?

Comment: @AngusL what's the definition of maximum?

Comment: A maximum is an element of a set such that it is greater or equal than all the elements of that set?

Comment: @AngusL Exactly. So, therefore, there must exist some $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)=\lambda$, right? Because $\lambda$ is an element of the set $\{f(x)|x\in[a,b]\}$, do you agree?

Comment: Okay, what now?

Comment: @AngusL Well. You know that $\lambda=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in[a,b]$. And you know that $\forall x\in [a,b]: f(x)<1$. It shouldn't be hard, from here, to conclude that $\lambda < 1$, right?

Comment: Can it be concluded with $\lambda = f(x_0) < 1$ since $ f(x) < 1 \forall x \in [a,b]$ therefore $\lambda$ < 1? (Which is basically what you just said)

Comment: @AngusL Yes, exactly. My point is just that this sounds obvious, but you still have to know *why* it is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of the Extreme Value Theorem, which states that any continuous function on a closed interval must attain a maximum and a minimum. In this case, you would let $\lambda$ be the maximum value of $f$ over $[a,b]$. For more information about the theorem and how to prove it, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact, $\lambda = \max \{ {f(x):x \in [a,b]\}}$ exists. We have $ \lambda <1.$